# SharePoint 2013 website does not scroll on Android phones

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, custom-masterpage, mobile, chrome

Our organization is using an on-prem version of SharePoint 2013 with a custom masterpage. We discovered that when using the combination of an Android phone with the Google Chrome browser to open our SharePoint 2013 website (www.sdcoe.net), the page will load perfectly, but will not scroll.

I've researched online for potential solutions and had no luck. I was not the original designer of the masterpage and am trying unravel what they may have done that created this problem.

Any thoughts or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of current master page and Try following steps:

In the Master page, look for this:

```
<body scroll="no" onload="javascript:_spBodyOnLoadWrapper();">
```

and replace with this:

```
<body scroll="no>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') 
    {
       _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();
     }
 });
</script>
```

If the problem still persists, I would suggest to try the following solution: [Kyle Schaeffer: SHAREPOINT 2010 SCROLLING](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2010-scrolling/)(It is for 2010 but you can try for 2013 as well)